# Connect Arduino + WiFi Shield to Raspberry Pi

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi, raspberrypi

I want to send collected data (temperature sensor) from my Arduino via the WiFi shield to my Raspberry Pi. Can I do that with the WiFi library that exists in Arduino IDE ?

Comment: Yes.  You could do something like run a simple TCP server on the pi, or perhaps something more complex like an MQTT-based setup, either with the pi itself as the broker or through a traditional broker either on the local network or the cloud.  At present your question lacks specifics, perhaps you should look at existing examples first.  Also keep in mind that an ESP8266 by itself may be preferable to an ATmega - based Arduino plus a shield.

Comment: I would just want it as simple as possible. Collect temperature from my balcony and send it via the local network to my Pi while I execute a python script on my Pi which waits to receive data from a local port (say 8088) and print out the data it received. To be more specific I would like to send the collected data from my Arduino to the IP address of my Pi.

Comment: Good, a web search should readily find you plenty of examples.  Questions should generally be asked after you search and find something specifically confusing or that does not work as expected, not as a substitute for research.

Comment: Yes, all right. I also searched but haven't found until now exactly what I wanted and I want to be sure before I buy certain things. However, hank you for your time and help!

Comment: Do you have power on the balcony? Cause if you have to run of batteries, using wifi isn't very energy efficient.

Comment: @Gerben Yes, I have power at the balcony!